# Should I create a different test function for each role?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898427/should-i-create-a-new-test-method-for-each-assertion) however I would like to know what the common practice is for the next situation. I have several roles in a web I'm creating, only one role can create the others, now I wonder if for the others I can test in just 1 test function. Something like:

```
def test_cannot_create_user(self):
  for role in ['role_1','role_2','role_3']: #roles that can't create
    for user  in ['role_1','role_2','role_3','role_4']: # all roles
      # assign user to a role
      # user with role fails on creating user
      # do assertions
      # remove user from group
```

Or should I create a function for each role and for each role to fail to be created?

Answer (score 1):

> Design is what we do to get more of what we want than we would get by just doing it.

When we are refactoring (as in red green refactor), the structure of our tests doesn't matter very much, because any test failure is always a consequence of the change that we just made - we don't need fine grain reporting, because we already know where the problem is.

But when we are doing a merge with someone else's code, having a clear report of a failure means that we can more clearly guess where we need to look for the problem that has been introduced.

When we are trying to inspect our test reports, then one of the things we care about in an audit is "what did we test" - having a clear enumeration of the cases in that report is better aligned with that goal than is expecting people to dig into the test details.

Horses for courses

What you can do in some frameworks is create a "parameterized" test, where you have a single test function, that accepts input arguments, with those arguments also being copied into the test report.

In your case, that might look something like

```
def test_cannot_create_user(self, role):
    # your test code here
```

A good video to review would be [Kevlin Henney's 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azoucC_fwzw&t=43m53s), where he discusses some test design considerations for a simple Gregorian leap year calculation; how should you design your tests if you want them to accurately describe your requirements.